# Custom Database Driver - DLL COM or dLL

Tags: dll, com, interop

I am creating a driver to my custom database. 
I imagine if it is going to be a pure DLL or a DLL COM.

For example, the fbclient.dll, from Firebird, is a COM or a simple DLL?
I imagine it is a pure DLL. I tried to register it using regsvr32 and it was not successful. 
Why is it not a COM?

Thanks!

Comment: Because they didn't feel the need to code for COM?  :P  You don't just randomly decide to code as a COM object.  It has to be designed for that.

Comment: I know you must designed it to be a COM. But if this driver will be consumed from other programming languages, i imagine that using a COM will make the life easier for the developers. Why did the choose a plain DLL?

Comment: If it exports a C API, then it's already simplified things far more than a COM object ever will.  C APIs are as close to universal as things get.

Comment: OK! But if I export a C API, Is it easy to consume, for example, in delphi, vb?

Comment: They simply chose not to. You should probably ask them why they did it that way. A plain C API is about the simplest way to export an interface (although it may introduct types that are hard to map in some languages).

Comment: I use the firebird DLL as an example. What about others database drivers? Are they COM or plain DLL? I imagine that a database api is very simple, so probably, thats why they choose a plain DLL....

Comment: There's no rule that says a database driver has to be implemented as a set of COM components. Actually the best approach is to first implement a plain C API and then build COM components on top of that if there's a need. And most database API-s are pretty complex so I don't think that was the reason behind their choice.